# iterating from 0 to 100 and printing the sum of all evens and the sum of all odds as array

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I am trying to iterate from 0 to 100 and trying to print the sum of even numbers and odd numbers as array, like this `[2550, 2500]`.

```
let m=0;

for(let i=0;i<=100;i++) { 
  m = m + i;
}

console.log(Array.from(String(m)));
```

but this code is returning  `['2', '5', '0', '0']`

Can anyone please show me how can I print both the sums as array?

Also if someone could help me with the code for putting this code into other conditional statement so that I can get both, the sum of odd numbers and sum of even numbers. I am facing issue deciding which one to use here, else if, if else....

Comment: *"I'm trying..."*: can you explain why you thought you had to use `String` and `Array.from` functions? I'd like to understand why you used those...

Comment: I think the classical trick to do this kind of calculation without a loop is applicable here, with some little tinkering. But admittedly, that is not solving the data type problem you are asking about. Just think of this when for the exercise after the next you get a TLE.

Comment: @trincot I want to print the output as array

Answer (score 2):

You just need to check the reminder of the number(i), if it's zero then it is even else it's odd.

```
let m=0,k=0;
for(let i=0;i<=100;i++)
{ 
if(i%2==0)m+=i
    else k+=i;
}
```

then `console.log([m,k]);`

Comment: If I misunderstood your question just comment here.

Comment: Hi Chang, I got the outputs but I am not able to print them as array, this is where I got stuck.

Comment: print them as array? Try console.log(JSON.stringify([m,k]));

Answer (score 1):

Your code is calculating the sum of all the numbers in the range of 0-100.

`m` will have the sum of range(0-100) that is `5050`.

```
for(let i=0;i<=100;i++) { 
  m = m + i;
}
```

This line will split the digits of variable `m` and make an array of it.

```
console.log(Array.from(String(m)));

['5','0','5','0']
```

You can have two variables for `even_sum` and `odd_sum` and then check if `i` is odd then add it to `odd_sum` else add it to `even_sum`.

```
let even_sum=0;
let odd_sum=0;

for(let i=0;i<=100;i++) { 
    if (i%2==0)
        even_sum+=i;
    else
        odd_sum+=i;
}
```

To return the values as array, you can do -

```
console.log([even_sum,odd_sum])
```

Comment: Yes I just noticed I was printing the sum of all numbers, anyway you saved me from using the big code that I was using to convert it into array

Answer (score 1):

As you tagged the question with [math](/questions/tagged/math) I think the mathematics of [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) should be mentioned here:

```js
function sumOddEven(n) {
    const floor = Math.floor(n / 2);
    const ceil = Math.ceil(n / 2);
    return [ceil * ceil, floor * (1 + floor)];
}

console.log(sumOddEven(100))
```

Without function:

```js
const n = 100; // Example
const floor = Math.floor(n / 2);
const ceil = Math.ceil(n / 2);
const arr = [ceil * ceil, floor * (1 + floor)];
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, could you also suggest what could be used except functions to perform this?

Comment: I added an alternative to my answer... Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, just saw it thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use an array to sum each parity individually.

```js
m=[0,0];
for (i=0;i<101;i++)
m[i%2]+=i;
console.log(m);
```